# Replace binary form 0->1 and 1->0 value - perl

Tags: perl

In my script i am dealing with binary value and i need to replace 0->1 and 1->0 at one place.

example :
input digit = 10101001
output digit = 01010110

I tried `$string =~ s/1/0/;` and `reverse function` but that is getting fail to give me correct out put.

can some one help me out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [tr](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tr.html):

```
my $str = '10101001';

$s =~ tr/01/10/;

print "$s\n";
```

Outputs:

```
01010110
```

Answer (score 5):

If your input string has only those two possibilities `0` and `1`, then you can use substitution in a multi-stage approach:

```
$str =~ s/1/x/g;  # all 1's to x
$str =~ s/0/1/g;  # all 0's to 1
$str =~ s/x/0/g;  # all x's to 0
```

This is not a bad option for languages that only provide substitutions, but Perl also has an atomic translation feature:

```
$str =~ tr/01/10/;
```

which will work just as well (better, really, since it's less code and probably less passes over the data).

Answer (score 2):

You could also go mathy on this and use the bitwise XOR operator `^`...

```
my $input  = '10101001';
my $binval = oct( '0b'.$input );
my $result = $binval ^ 0b11111111;
printf "%08b\n", $result;
```

...which will also give you `01010110`.

This of course has the downside of being dependent on the length of the bit input string. The given solution only works for 8-bit values. It wouldn't be hard to generalize for any number of bits, though.

---

To incorporate [Lưu Vĩnh Phúc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/995714/l%C6%B0u-v%C4%A9nh-ph%C3%BAc)'s comment - you can also use the bitwise NOT operator `~`. Again, the implementation is dependent on the number of bits as you need to truncate the result:

```
my $input  = '10101001';
my $binval = oct( '0b'.$input );
print substr( sprintf ( '%b', ~$binval ), -8 )."\n";
```

Comment: why don't use `my $result = ~$binval`?

Comment: Because it would also "fill" any unset bits - for example on this 64-bit system I'm in front of right now, it will return `1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111101010110`

Comment: I don't know about size of int type in perl but you can mask out the high bits easily

Comment: Yeah, sure. It doesn't get prettier by this, but I'll add it as alternative.